# unity 2d platformer tutorial broken death and triggers not working

Tags: unity-game-engine

ok i have no idea what i did but now "my" code doesn't work aka the unity 2d platformer learning template isn't working properly, so the very nice death mechanic no longer works
[this is the error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5tWd.png) and as you can see i have no idea what went wrong, all i did was change sprites and edit some numbers like speed and that stuff and i tried to make a trigger thing for confetti that didn't work and so i deleted it but every time i played before i deleted it the triggers wouldn't work and nor do they work now. Sounds like fun trying to figure out what is broken when i didn't touch anything important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script is trying to refrence a variable that's unassigned could you send the code of PlayerDeath script, i assume you haven't assigned a variable inside of the inspector

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/150kt6odoXMUSd3mgw54LSDWRgHbWLIq3zI9genFBz5E/edit?usp=sharing
this has the image of the code

Comment: Remove
model.virtualCamera.m_Follow = null;
model.virtualCamera.m_LookAt = null;
and try running this again

Comment: thanks that worked BUT now here is another bug now when my player spawns nothing works like i cant move left or right up down nothing. you can see the bug and the code for player spawn in the doc again

Comment: oh hay i got it so the problem was once again the stupid model.virtualCamera.m code that broke it anyway thanks for your help